# JAVAC.exe file missed after installed Java7 in Windows7(64bit)

Tags: java, installation, javac

I recently installed **JAVA7** in my Windows7 64bit Laptop.After that Java is not running properly and i am unable to found

> **JAVAC.exe** in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin.

I uninstalled and installed 3 to 4 times, but no use.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to install JRE or JDK?

Comment: `javac` isn't under jre.. it's under jdk

Comment: Can you please google and check the difference between jdk and jre. As all mentioned, you are trying to find a command in jre which exists only in jdk not in jre.

Comment: The "JDK" is the Java Development Kit. I.e., the JDK is bundle of software that you can use to develop Java based software. The "JRE" is the Java Runtime Environment. I.e., the JRE is an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine which actually executes Java programs. **I MISSED THIS PART :(**

Answer (score 4):

Since your title says javac, I will assume that you are trying to install Java to compile programs, you can grab the latest development kit from [Oracle here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

`javac` is located under jdk([version](http://www.javatester.org/version.html)) where. In your case above, since you are on x64 Windows *(and provided you use the one I linked to)*, you can install the kit and add the following to your path:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin`

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this out.  They arent saying the JRE folder, they are saying look at 
C:/ program files / java/ JDKx.x.x-45/ bin 
I made the mistake of looking in 
C:/ program files / java/ JDKx.x.x-45/JRE/ bin